# Running two separate scripts while terminal is closed?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Basically what I need is to activate two separate scripts that work at the same time and then close the ssh session on RaspberryPi and let them run in the background. Since I don't have much experience with this, I would appreciate any suggestions on the best way to do this.

Comment: It's not clear to me what Python has to do with your question. Are you trying to call a python script that starts a SSH connection to a RaspberryPi that calls two scripts on the Pi? Do you care about their results? Do you want to know when they finished or just call them both at the same time and close the ssh connection? In order to be able to help you we need more information on what exactly your are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is not so much a Python but a Linux question about starting progamms automatically. So I would suggest asking in the respective stack exchange. Additionally it is important to know if you expect these scripts to run a graphical user interface or be just background processes.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to make this happen is using `nohup` and send the process background.

```
nohup script1.sh &
nohup script2.sh &
```

But I strongly recommend a supervising mechanism.

Comment: What would you recommend for a supervising mechanism?

Comment: Since the post labeled as python, I suggest supervisord (http://supervisord.org/)